# newline in macro recording

Tags: macro

Let's say I record a macro `n` that generates the following text:

```
1
2
```

When I ask for the content with `"np` it outputs:

`i1^M2^M^[`

So I append in `.vimrc` file:

```
let @n = 'i1^M2^M^['
```

if I save `.vimrc` and then I call it with `@n` in a new file, it outputs the string above literally.....

How should I represent the newline key in configuration file?

Comment: Macros are often a poor substitute for a mapping when you want to save them. Did you type `^` then `M`, or `<C-v><C-m>`?

Comment: Did you use `"np` to paste the escaped characters `^M` and `^[` into the vim script?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I typed `^` then `M`, the second way doest not work either.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I've found is:

`let @n = "i1\n2\n\e"`

however the following does not work:

`let @n = 'i1\n2\n\e'`

Comment: `the following does not work` Please, read `:h expr-"` and `:h expr-'`